# Save knitr chunk to R file

Tags: r, knitr

In knitr there is a `read_chunk` function which read external code into a chunk. Is it possible to reverse the process. That is, make a function `write_chunk()` which save the source code in the chunk to an R file? The file name may the same as the chunk name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a solution using hooks. Add the following hook:

```
knit_hooks$set(write_chunk = function(before, options, envir) {
    if (before) {
      fileConn<-file(paste0("chunk_",options$label,".R") )
      writeLines(options$code, fileConn)
      close(fileConn)
    }
})
```

and use option `<<chunk-name, write_chunk=TRUE>>` in the header of a chunk.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following syntax

```
Stangle(file = "Your_code.Rnw",output="Code.R"):
```

But this I can prove the following error:

```
#Error: ‘Your_code.Rnw’ is not ASCII and does not declare an encoding
```

Adding the following parameter (encoding = "UTF-8"), the coding problem is solved

```
Stangle("Your_code.Rnw",output="Code.R",encoding="utf8")
```

Comment: This is not want I want. I only want to save the source code from a single chunk. Moreover, the function must work inside the Rnw, so you can e.g. apply a function on the saved R file in the next chunk.